# why is my sub, deleting a row of data in my other sheet - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets "Ark1" and "Ark2". i get my data from "Ark2" and put them in "Ark1". my "Sub X" fuction should transpose the data from horizontal to vertical with the dates. But when i run "sub x" it is deleting a row of data in "Ark2" where i get my data. I have all the code in one module.

```
    Sub x()

Dim lngDataColumns As Long
Dim lngDataRows As Long

lngDataColumns = 3
lngDataRows = 50


For t = 1 To lngDataRows

Range("l2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("f1:h1").Value)

Range("M2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("f1:h1").Offset(t).Value)

Next t

End Sub
```

Here is a pictuere of the deleted data.

[image: deleted data]

and here is a picture of what i wnat it to do in "Ark1" painted in colours.

i hope you can help

[image]

Comment: In `Range("l2").Offset(((t - 1) * lngDataColumns) - 1, 0).Resize(lngDataColumns, 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Range("f1:h1").Value)`

Range("L2") and Range("F1:H1") are both in the same sheet. Are you copying the values to be transposed to L2? Or are you just not referencing the correct sheet?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this kind of issues, **always qualify your objects fully**.
Where you write `Range("A1")`, you should instead write:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your sheet").Range("A1")
```

Where:

- `ThisWorkbook` qualifies the object in the workbook where the code is running (the default, instead, is `ActiveWorkbook` which might be something else in the moment where the code runs).
- `Sheets("Your sheet")` makes sure you run in the good worksheet.

This is of course to be done everywhere you say just `Range("something")`.

**Tip:** if you think your code would get heavy by doing this, then you can define your range on top of your code and use it by name lately, for example:

```
Dim myRng1 As Range: Set myRng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Your sheet").Range("your range")
...
...
myRng1.DoSomething()
myRng1.DoSomethingElse()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    With ws1
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

If you use the name outside the brackets:

[image]

or

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

you use the name in the brackets:

[image]